Incorrect/confusing versioning of Go package located in non-root folder of git
I have a package at https://github.com/and3rson/fastmsg, it's located in a go subdir since it's a multi-language monorepo, thus I cannot keep the Go package at repo root.
Latest commit is tagged as v1.0.1, however:

Version at pkg.go.dev is shown as v0.0.0-xxx-yyy
Running go get github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go@latest also fetches v0.0.0-xxx-yyy with some confusing output:
# Why is and3rson/fastmsg fetched if the actual package is and3rson/fastmsg/go?
go: downloading github.com/and3rson/fastmsg v1.0.1
go: downloading github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go v0.0.0-20240819225607-785e9a27b194
go: added github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go v0.0.0-20240819225607-785e9a27b194


Running go get github.com/and3rson/fastmsg (excluding /go suffix) fetches correct v1.0.1, however the package is not usable since the real package is inside go subdir.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or my (somehow) incorrect usage of the Go packaging system, but the observed behavior seems very unintuitive to me.
I also could not find any discussions describing this issue or documenting the correct usage of packages located in subdirs.
Expected behavior
I'm expecting a package that's located in a subdir to behave the same way as a top-level package.
Basically, I'm expected to see the following:
$ go get github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go
go: downloading github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go v1.0.1
go: added github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go v1.0.1


is the commit 785e9a27b194 not v1.0.1?

Your repository is not tagged correctly. From “Mapping versions to commits:”

If a module is defined in a subdirectory within the repository, that is, the module subdirectory portion of the module path is not empty, then each tag name must be prefixed with the module subdirectory, followed by a slash. For example, the module golang.org/x/tools/gopls is defined in the gopls subdirectory of the repository with root path golang.org/x/tools. The version v0.4.0 of that module must have the tag named gopls/v0.4.0 in that repository.

This means your module github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go exists, but is not tagged (“Tagged version” is unchecked), while github.com/and3rson/fastmsg is tagged, but has no go module.
When you tag your repository with go/v1.0.1, go get github.com/and3rson/fastmsg/go@v1.0.1 will work.
